# I have a React/Redux issue: Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access '__WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT__' before initialization

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-redux

I have a problem with my React project, my application has just stopped displaying properly, and I'm getting Webpack errors on my console. I have tried debugging still hasn't solved the problem

Here's the error, I'm getting from my console for context

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access '__WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT__' before initialization
    at Module.default (userSlice.js:35:1)
    at ./src/firebase.js (firebase.js:22:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
    at ./src/components/Header.js (store.js:3:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
    at ./src/App.js (bundle.js:19:76)
```

[Screenshot of my console and application screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ul0vI.png)

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { auth, provider } from "../firebase";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import {
  selectUserName,
  selectUserPhoto,
  setSignOutState,
  setUserLoginDetails,
} from "../features/user/userSlice";
import { useEffect } from "react";

const Header = (props) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const userName = useSelector(selectUserName);
  const userPhoto = useSelector(selectUserPhoto);

  // redirects logged in user to home page

  useEffect(() => {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged(async (user) => {
      if (user) {
        setUser(user);
        navigate.push("/home");
      }
    });
  }, [userName]);

  // sets user login details in redux store
  const handleAuth = () => {
    // check if user is logged in
    if (!userName) {
      auth
        .signInWithPopup(provider)
        .then((result) => {
          setUser(result.user);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          alert(error.message);
        });
    } else if (userName) {
      auth
        .SignOut()
        .then(() => {
          dispatch(setSignOutState());
          navigate.push("/");
        })
        .catch((err) => alert(err.message));
    }
  };
  const setUser = (user) => {
    dispatch(
      setUserLoginDetails({
        name: user.displayName,
        email: user.email,
        photo: user.photoURL,
      })
    );
  };

  return (
    <Nav>
      <Logo>
        <img src="/images/logo.svg" alt="Disney" />
      </Logo>

      {!userName ? (
        <Login onClick={handleAuth}>Login</Login>
      ) : (
        <>
          <NavMenu>
            <a href="/home">
              <img src="/images/home-icon.svg" alt="HOME" />
              <span>HOME</span>
            </a>
            <a href=" ">
              <img src="/images/search-icon.svg" alt="WATCH" />
              <span>SEARCH</span>
            </a>
            <a href=" ">
              <img src="/images/original-icon.svg" alt="ORIGINAL" />
              <span>ORIGINAL</span>
            </a>
            <a href=" ">
              <img src="/images/movie-icon.svg" alt="MOVIES" />
              <span>MOVIES</span>
            </a>
            <a href=" ">
              <img src="/images/series-icon.svg" alt="SERIES" />
              <span>SERIES</span>
            </a>
          </NavMenu>
          <SignOut>
            <UserImg src={userPhoto} alt={userName} />
            <Dropdown>
              <span onClick={handleAuth}>Sign Out</span>
            </Dropdown>
          </SignOut>
        </>
      )}
    </Nav>
  );
};

// Styled Components
***
//

export default Header;
```

So this file below is my initialize firebase file, this is for the google sign in popup provider:

```
// Initialize Firebase
const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
/*this is line22:*/ 
const db = firebase.firestore();
//
const auth = firebase.auth();
const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
const storage = firebase.storage();


  export { auth, provider, storage, firebaseApp};
  export default db;
```

The createSlice is to create an empty initial state and collect the user login details taken by the browser from the google auth popup and store that payload to the DB. Check here:

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const initialState = {
    name: '',
    email: '',
    password: '',
};

const userSlice = createSlice ({
    name: 'user',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        setUserLoginDetails: (state, action) => {
            state.name = action.payload.name;
            state.email = action.payload.email;
            state.photo = action.payload.photo;
        },

        setSignOutState: (state) => {
            state.name = 'null';
            state.email = 'null';
            state.photo = 'null';
        },
    },
})
```

this is the only instance of userSlice being imported into any other file side the header file
[store.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHEhs.png)

Here's the screenshot of my src/firebase.js file:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLtQ5.png)

Comment: I would move your styled component definitions up so they're defined **before** you use them

Comment: Thanks, for the advice, would take it into a note. @Phil

Comment: The error message isn't matching the code you're showing. Are you sure you're looking at `src/firebase.js`

Comment: Why do you have `import firebase from "./firebase"` in `firebase.js`? That's just an infinite import loop

Comment: That makes sense...I'm sure I made this error while I was debugging, but I've rectified that now, but it keeps showing me firebase is not defined for some reason.

Comment: You seem to be mixing Firebase v8 and v9 syntax. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#web-version-9_1

Comment: Will check it now